# Creating Powershell script for VMWare using veeam

Tags: powershell, veeam

I am trying to create a script to automate the Veeam backup using PowerShell.

I know in the free version I only have 2 options (Veeamzip and Quick Backup).

I have a Drobo on the network with the share setup and accessible.

I have gone into all the VMWare Hypervisors and created an account with the proper permissions to run a backup.

I am down to creating the syntax for running the backup.

I am confused when I look at their document. I am not sure if I am supposed to use a copy, replication, a backup job, or what.

If I can get the initial syntax to run a backup of one machine I know I can build the script.

Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can not be done with this version of VMWare.